# Trouble with Form API and #states

Tags: 7, forms

I have a form built and need a fieldset to collapse/expand based on the value of another checkbox field.

The checkbox code is:

```
$form[$serving_key] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#title' => t($serve_size)
);
```

The fieldset is:

```
$form[$fieldset_key] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => TRUE,
        '#states' => array(
            'expanded' => array(
                ':input[name="' . $serving_key . '"]' => array('checked' => TRUE)
            )
        )
);
```

These are in a foreach loop, and $serving_key at any point is 'serving_large', 'serving_small', etc.  The corresponding $fieldset_key is 'fieldset_large', 'fieldset_small', etc.

This looks like it should work in the form_example_states_form example code.  What am I missing?

Comment: did you try it without the variables?

Comment: no, because the variable values were exactly as expected.

Comment: Hello. Could you make title more specific? Ideally title alone should be an answerable question, and question's body should work only as clarification. Of course ideal not always can be reached, but I'm sure you can get it better than it is now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot about unique keys in your form elements. Here is a working example:

```
function test_form($form, &$form_state) {

  // your size options
  $options = array('small', 'medium', 'big');

  $form['checkboxes'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
  );

  foreach ($options as $size) {

    $form['checkboxes'][$size . '_checkbox'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox', 
      '#title' => t($size . ' size'),
    );

    $form[$size . '_field'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset', 
      '#title' => t($size . ' size'), 
      '#collapsible' => TRUE,
      '#collapsed' => TRUE,
      '#states' => array(
        'expanded' => array(
          ':input[name="' . $size. '_checkbox"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
        ),
      ),
    );

    $form[$size . '_field']['some_info'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textarea', 
      '#title' => t($size . ' size textarea'),
    );
  }
  return $form;
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: The keys are unique.  I want the checkboxes next to their fieldsets.  Is that not possible?

Comment: In your snippet of code there is a lack of: 1. The `#title` attribute of the collapsible fieldsets (they are required if you want them collapsible). 2. `textarea` elements. 3. Not sure if the keys are unique, you only say so. That's why I decided to write an example, so you would be able to find what's missing very easy. If you want the checkboxes next to their fieldsets, just remove the `$form['checkboxes']` element and the key `['checkboxes']` from each checkbox. You can arrange your form elements however you want. Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: 1. Ah, I'll try that next.  2.  Do I need a textarea element?  I do have a textarea inside each of my fieldsets.  3.  They are unique.  The checkboxes are siblings to their fieldsets.  The only child elements are under the fieldsets.  I'll try the titles...

Comment: Looks like the #title attribute of the fieldsets were my problem.  I added them and all is well.  Thanks!